# How much does public transit cost in Tokyo or in Komatsu?

Tags: japan, costs

I had applied for MEXT scholarship and I gradually plan my cost of living in case I got accepted. (Better safe rather than sorry.) And as part of my moving arround I will use public transit. The possible cities I may get accepted are either Tokyo or Komatsu.

Hence, I wanted to know how much it roughly costs to use Japaneese public transist for daily commuting.

Comment: This question is not about expatriates, and as such is off-topic

Comment: @Scott Earle It’s connected to applying for a student visa, so on topic IMHO

Comment: @Traveller, *Any and all* expenses can be said to be tied to applying for a student visa. But public transport expenses are also tied to living in Tokyo (or Komatsu) in general. Even native residents must consider travel/commute expenses. There is nothing here that is specific or relatively unique to being an Expat.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic, not unique to the Expat experience.

Comment: @ouflak However, native residents are much better placed to consider these things than a would-be student immigrant trying to figure costs out from outside Japan

Comment: @Traveller, Maybe, and I don't it's a bad question that can get useful answers for both expats and locals. It's just that broad questions like this that can apply to anybody don't really fit here.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Tokyo, in Tokyo a one way ticket is approx 200¥ and a monthly pass around 10,000¥. I couldn't find data for Komatsu.